# Set-WmiInstance -Arguments $Variable Hangs

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update the RDP_Listening SSL thumbprint. I have spent hours reading examples and am not able to figure out why it is not working for me.

First I get the thumbprint and set the variable $Thumbprint. Then use the preferred PowerShell `Set-WmiInstance` only for it to hang and PowerShell ISE red button never goes away.

```
$Thumbprint = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Out-GridView -Title Thumbprint -PassThru

$path = (Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").__path
Set-WmiInstance -Path $path -Arguments @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="$Thumbprint"}
```

Execution policy is unrestricted, the certificate has a private key, the certificate has enhanced feature 'Server Authentication'. ISE is running as Administrator. I am guessing that the variable isn't being read?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to expand the Thumbprint property. You're getting the entire certificate object right now. Add `|Select -ExpandProperty Thumbprint` to the end of your first line and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked, I didn't even realize I was getting the entire obeject. I checked the uparrow for you. Not sure how to give credit to you for answering it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand the Thumbprint property. You're getting the entire certificate object right now. Add `|Select -ExpandProperty Thumbprint` to the end of your first line.